# Can anyone identify this insect on my aloe plant?

Tags: identification

[image: Aloe plant with insects]

Can anyone identify the insects on my aloe plant? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a nymph (immature form) of  a species of leaf-footed bug in the family Coreidae.  https://bugguide.net/node/view/245/bgimage  In North America, they are colloquially called "squash bugs", because some species, such as Anasa tristis, are pests of squash plants and other cucurbits.They are also called “leaf-footed bugs” due to the leaf-like expansions some species have on their hind legs.

Some coreids, such as Phyllomorpha laciniata, exhibit parental care by carrying their eggs. This behavior can protect the eggs from parisitism.
https://extension.umn.edu/yard-and-garden-insects/squash-bugs